# How make draggable widget in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, widget, wpf-controls

I want to make draggable widgets in WPF C#, and I am struggling with how to make some controls to be draggable with mouse.

For example
http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2009/08/8-12-09widgets.jpg

how make widgets like this in C# and make them draggable.

Comment: Please read [this post](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). It contains very useful information that will help you throughout your entire programming career.

Comment: thank you , I will read it:)